# How can I get all the rows of the MAX value in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I would like to know how I can get all the rows with the maximum order value based on Cat 1,Cat 2 and Month here. I tried using Partition and MAX but he gives me the same max value even if the month is different.

[image]

What I tried:

```
Select
ID
,Cat1
,Cat2
,Month
,max([Order]) Over
      (Partition By [Cat1],[Cat2],[Month]) as max_ord
from table
Where [order] = max_ord
```

What I need:

[image: tab result]

Comment: Pick a database, any database, but **please** do NOT SPAM tags!

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Square brackets are used in SQL-Server, not MySQL or Oracle.

Comment: Hmm, funny, the only one not on a tag :) @Barmar

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your query within a subquery as the following:

```
Select ID ,Cat1 ,Cat2 ,Month ,[Order]
From
(
  Select ID, Cat1 ,Cat2 ,Month ,[Order],
  MAX([Order]) Over (Partition By [Cat1],[Cat2],[Month]) As max_ord
  From table_name
) T
Where [order] = max_ord
Order By ID
```

Or, you could give it a try with CTE:

```
With CTE As
(
  Select ID, Cat1 ,Cat2 ,Month ,[Order],
  MAX([Order]) Over (Partition By [Cat1],[Cat2],[Month]) As max_ord
  From table_name
)
Select ID ,Cat1 ,Cat2 ,Month ,[Order]
From CTE
Where [order] = max_ord
Order By ID
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xsvNdryR).